# How to know if a branch is closed using it's branch name?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

My question is pretty straight forward - Is there a command on mercurial where you can just check if a branch is closed or not using it's branch name?

```
hg branch_name status

- closed
```

Something along those lines . .?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to take a look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40385648/5619416 . As far as I can tell, you can't check the remote repositories, so you'll have to have them cloned on local.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a repo with this history:

```
> hg log -G
_  changeset:   3:fde10e155a4c
|  branch:      two
|  tag:         tip
|  summary:     close branch two
|
o  changeset:   2:dec57b99f3d8
|  branch:      two
|  parent:      0:4b5a1a000402
|  summary:     add c
|
| o  changeset:   1:1b3feb10b30e
|/   branch:      one
|    summary:     add b
|
@  changeset:   0:4b5a1a000402
   summary:     Add a
```

There are 3 branches: `default`, `one` and `two`. Branch `two` is closed.

We can use `hg branches` as follows:

The `--closed` option prints also the closed branches:

```
> hg branches --closed
one                            1:1b3feb10b30e
two                            3:fde10e155a4c (closed)
default                        0:4b5a1a000402 (inactive)
```

So with a simple shell pipe with grep:

```
> hg branches --closed | grep closed | grep two
two                            3:fde10e155a4c (closed)
>
```

As a counter example, using branch `one` gives empty output, since it is not closed:

```
> hg branches --closed | grep closed | grep one
>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hg log -r "branch('branch_name') and head() and (closed())" -T "{branch}"
```

What I have used was this.
This basically points out the branch name following the `T` as a template.

Replace `branch_name` with your branch name.